# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using a `php` code that contains:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This `php` file runs perfectly on `localhost` using `XAMPP` but when I try to run it on my own **Shared Hosting** server it gives this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `PHPUnit:Autoload.php` the colon doesn't seem right?

Comment: Yea it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: A possible reason that this might happen is that your php include_path is not set correctly. Please make sure you have the appropriate path to PEAR available. For my WAMP installation it would be:
``include_path=".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\PEAR\PEAR"``
However, it will most likely be different on your system.

Comment: Your path to your file is not correct.  It can't find the file.

Comment: @MarcoBax how to check that ?

Comment: @durbnpoisn So do you have any clue to try to solve this ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan Use phpinfo(); for that, it will show you your include paths.

Comment: @MarcoBax unfortunately i'm on shared hosting which means phpinfo(); is disabled for security reasons

Comment: Ask your host if they support PHPUnit, but PHPUnit should probably not be run on production websites anyway :)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan require_once `__DIR__ . '/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';` not helped for you ?

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov no it didn't solve the problem either, i just don't know why it works perfectly on my local machine using `XAMPP` and it doesn't work on a live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a very old pear version of PHPUnit installed locally. It is [deprecated](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method) for ages. Instead you need to add phpunit to your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.0.*" //or whatever version you need
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remove `require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';` and update composer? Sorry if it was not clear from the answer, but this library should not be used.

Comment: If you didn't need PHPUnit on production, why would you even include it ?